# How to configure router so that component was added inside or is instead?

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

Angular 2-4
By default, the router adds component after a router-outlet tag.
How to configure router so that component was added inside or is instead?

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<inserted-component></inserted-component>
```

Comment: To put it inside the router-outlet, you should add your inserted-component inside the activated route component

Comment: That's not supported. Trying to do this is pointless. It doesn't fulfill any purpose anyway. What do you want/need this for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no setting for this, you could probably extend the [`RouterOutlet`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.1/packages/router/src/directives/router_outlet.ts#L14-L147) [directive](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet) with an own implementation, but this will be a lot of cumbersome work, for a little gain.

You could however also create your own 'outlet', for instance:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'my-router-outlet',
   template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class MyRouterOutlet {}
```

Now the view is inserted in the `my-router-outlet` tag. This might solve the issue you have